# How to make the difference between two consecutive elements of a vector and remove the one ending with two zeros if the difference is less than 10

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I am trying to generate a vector breaks_x which is the result of another vector break_init. If the difference between two successive elements of break_init is less than 10, the element ending with two zeros will be removed.
My code is always removing breaks_init[i] even if it not ending with two zeros.
Can anyone help please

```
break_init <- c(100,195,200,238,300,326,400,481,500,537,600,607,697,700,800,875,900,908,957)
breaks_x <- vector()
for(i in 1:(length(break_init) - 1))
{
  if (break_init[i+1] - break_init[i] >= 10) {
    breaks_x[i] <- break_init[i]
  } else {
    if (grepl("[00]$", as.character(break_init[i])) == TRUE){
      breaks_x[i] <- NA
    } else if (grepl("[00]$", as.character(break_init[i])) == FALSE) {
      breaks_x[i+1] <- NA
  } else {
      breaks_x[i] <- break_init[i]
  }
 }
}
[1]   0 100  NA 200 238 300 326 400 481 500 537  NA 607  NA 700 800 875  NA 908 957 #result breaks_x
[1]   0 100 195  NA 238 300 326 400 481 500 537  NA 607 697  NA 800 875  NA 908 957 #what I want my result to be
```

Comment: `[00]$` is not doing what you want, it is looking for a zero or a zero at the end of the string (not two zeroes); also, it will break when floating point "appears" in your days. I think you can do this in one step, no loops, something like this untested code: `x[c(F, diff(x) < 10) & x %% 100 < 1] <- NA`. No regex, no loops.

Answer (score 1):

r2evans has the right idea. Just a little modification to check both the forward and the backwards difference:

```
bln10 <- diff(break_init) < 10
breaks_x <- replace(break_init, (c(FALSE, bln10) | c(bln10, FALSE)) & break_init %% 100 == 0, NA)
breaks_x
# [1] 100 195  NA 238 300 326 400 481 500 537  NA 607 697  NA 800 875  NA 908 957
```

Comment: @jblood94, thanks for carrying on my suggested code; I wasn't able to test it at the time, it's good somebody else was able to complete it.